# javascript/typescript lodash.cloneDeep: circularity in archetype data leads to "call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, lodash, clone, stack-overflow, archetypes

(Posted as an [archetype issue](https://github.com/boosterfuels/archetype/issues/26))

archetype@0.13.0, using lodash.clonedeep@4.5.0, sometimes results in "call stack size exceeded", presumably due to circular references in the data, specifically encountered in:

- archetype/src/type.js  - `Type` constructor method
- archetype/src/index.js - `Archetype` constructor and visitObject methods

So, first questions: which uses of archetype are circular (and how detected), and can the circularities be avoided or addressed?

As for possible workarounds/solutions, which of the many deepClone alternatives would be appropriate?

One possible solution - [rfdc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfdc) - addresses circular structures, albeit at a %25 performance hit:

```
const clone = require('rfdc')({circles: true})
...
b = clone(a)
```

The key question its whether circularities can be eliminated, whether an across-the-board %25 performance reduction can be tolerated, or whether circularity can be detected, to determine which flavor of deep cloning should be applied.

Some (problematic) workarounds:

1. replace [lodash.cloneDeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) with [clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone), in each file:

- replace `const cloneDeep = require('lodash.clonedeep');` with `const clone = require('clone');`
- replace references to _.cloneDeep(...) with references to clone(...)

2. replace [lodash.cloneDeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) with [fclone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fclone), as discussed [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/3881).

The problem with each is that circular values are replaced with a string: '[Circular]', presumably problematic when dealing with types.

Ultimately, this needs to be fixed in archetype, as that's where reliance on lodash.deepClone breaks down.

Comment: Why are you not using the native `globalThis.structuredClone` available from Node 17.0.0?

Comment: @connexo - That's a question for the archetype maintainer. My application is currently at node 13, so unless there's a` globalThis.structuredClone` version for that, it wouldn't be an option.